# initialize to tinyMCE textarea and set content on selected tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

is it possible or can I initialize two textarea's with tinyMCE editor? I know I can set content to tinyMCE editor using (refer below)

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('test');
```

but what if I want to set content to a specific already tinyMCE editor initialized textarea e.g. the second textarea, is that even possible? or is there a way to do that?

Any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 230,
  theme: 'modern',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="t1"></textarea><br>
<button id="t1button">Set content to tinyMCE textarea 1</button><br><br>
<textarea id="t2"></textarea><br>
<button id="t2button">Set content to tinyMCE textarea 2</button><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target a specific TinyMCE editor using the get API method:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/class/tinymce.editormanager/#get

For example:

```
tinyMCE.get('t2').getContent()
tinyMCE.get('t2').setContent('...content here...')
```

...would target the TinyMCE instance that has a selector of an ID of 't2 '.

Comment: does not work like no errors but still the tinymce editor textarea is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see this TinyMCE Fiddle:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Dqfaab/4  It has two buttons that update two different TinyMCE instances by targeting the instance based on ID.